# Jasmine - Multiple it's, one asynchronous call

Tags: jasmine, jasmine-node

**Scenario**

I'm trying to do multiple `it` specs on a single external load rather than have the external data loaded EVERY time.

**Question**

How can I do this with a single call of `getExternalValue` while still keeping my `it` definitions?

**Ideas**

Currently I'm doing all the `expect`s in a single `it` block. I've also thought about storing the loaded value before my tests but then I'd have to find another way to make jasmine wait until the value is loaded.

## Code

```
function getExternalValue(callback) {
    console.log("getting external value");
    
    setTimeout(function() {
        callback(true);
    }, 2000);

    return false;
}

describe("mjaTestLambda()", function() {
    it("is truthy", function(done) {
        let truthy;
        truthy = getExternalValue(function(bool) {
            truthy = bool;
            expect(truthy).toBeTruthy();
            done();
        });
    });

    it("is falsy", function(done) {
        let truthy;
        truthy = getExternalValue(function(bool) {
            truthy = bool;
            expect(!truthy).toBeFalsy();
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: does `getExternalValue()` return a Promise?

Comment: @stealththeninja no but I️ see what you’re thinking and I️ like it. That definitely worth an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I do this with a single call of getExternalValue while still
>   keeping my it definitions?

Use `beforeEach()` or `beforeAll()` to get the resolved value. Personally I suggest before**Each**() as it will reset the value for each test and helps ensure a clean setup for each one.

I noticed your function has a callback parameter. Async/await is a useful pattern that works best when (1) you're writing async/await functions or (2) your functions return a Promise. If you need to keep the callback parameter, let me know and I'll update the following:

```
// returns Promise
function getExternalValue() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("getting external value");
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(true);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

describe("mjaTestLambda()", () => {

    let value;

    beforeAll(() => {
      return getExternalValue()
        .then((v) => { value = v; });
    });

    it("is truthy", () => {
      expect(v).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("is not falsy", () => {
      expect(!v).toBeFalsy();
    });
});
```

Comment: Let's say the wait time for getting the external value takes 10 seconds. Does that mean I'm waiting 20 seconds total for my tests? That's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Using beforeEach() would add 10 seconds **per test**. The risk with using beforeAll() is mutating the result between tests. I'll update my answer.